# JS Form submit not working in Safari, no errors

Tags: javascript, forms, safari, form-submit

I have a button which onclick downloads a file then submits a form which takes the user to the next page. The file downloads, but the form is not submitted as the page does not go to the specified 'action' url. This behavior only happens on safari, everything works on chrome and firefox. I have other pages which use form submit fine in safari. There are even other pages which download a file then submit a form when a button is clicked, and those work in safari, but this one specifically does not. Furthermore, there are no error messages in the console, and when I manually enter document.getElementById('the-form').submit() into the console after clicking the download button, the form submits as expected. I don't have a lot of experience with js and this issue is very confusing, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
btn.onclick = function(){
              saveAs(file); //using FileSaver library
              let url = '/next/?uparam1='+urlParams.get('uparam1')+'&uparam2='+p2.innerText;
              document.getElementById('param1').value = p1.innerText;
              document.getElementById('param2').value = p2.innerText;
              document.getElementById('param3').value = p3.innerText;
              var form = document.getElementById('the-form');
              form.setAttribute('action', url);
              form.submit();
            }
```

Comment: Having never used the `FileSaver` library, my suggestion might be off, but can you attach a callback to your `saveAs(file)`, and move your code (let url and the rest) there? Also, what happens if you put a simple `console.log` before and after calling `saveAs(file)`? And does your form on this specific page differ in any way from the other forms? For example, does it have a `target="_blank"` attribute, or anything which would  initiate opening of a new tab or a pop-up?

Comment: @FiddlingAway , I have tried adding console.log before and after the saveAs(), with the same result. Using a callback also didn't change the result. The other form which uses saveAs() then submit() also has an awaited fetch() after the saveAs() and before the submit(), otherwise it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue with 'saveAs' being asynchronous. The code following the call to 'saveAs' is being executed before the file download is completed and thus resulting in the form being submitted before the file download is finished.

Use the `.then` method to wrap your code within it, this will tell javascript to execute the remainder of the code in top to bottom manner.

```js
btn.onclick = function() {
  saveAs(file).then(function() {
    let url = '/next/?uparam1=' + urlParams.get('uparam1') + '&uparam2=' + p2.innerText;
    document.getElementById('param1').value = p1.innerText;
    document.getElementById('param2').value = p2.innerText;
    document.getElementById('param3').value = p3.innerText;
    var form = document.getElementById('the-form');
    form.setAttribute('action', url);
    form.submit();
  });
}
```

Comment: When I tried this, the file downloads, then I get the error ```TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'saveAs(file).then')```.

Comment: Also, the file download has always worked, the form just never submits. I have also tried awaiting saveAs(), but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you instead use Async/Await instead of the .then() method?

Comment: Yes, i tried that too, unfortunately didn't fix it